# Google Sheets formula to calculate how much time will take for money to get specific value in the future

Tags: google-sheets

Let's assume that I have 100$, and I put it in the bank and I get 4% per year. (every day I get part of  it)
How much time it will take until I have 150$?

What is the formula in Google Sheet for that?

I have checked Google Sheets formulas table and dindn't found something relevant (correct e if I wrong)

Answer (score 1):

It will take ten years and four months.

At the beginning, the 4% interest rate will get you about 1 cent per day in interest. The interest will compound, but it will grow pretty slowly. When the principal plus aggregated interest has reached $200, you will get about 2 cents per day.

To get a total of $50 in interest, you will need to wait several thousand days — 3774 days to be exact.

You can get a `15`-year table that shows the daily balance of your `$100` including `4%` of yearly compound interest like this:

`A1`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    "number of days", "aggregate savings"; 
    sequence(15 * 365, 1, 0), 
    100 
    * 
    (1 + (1 + 4% / 1) ^ (1 / 365) - 1) 
    ^ 
    sequence(15 * 365, 1, 0) 
  } 
)
```

The formula assumes that there are `365` days in a year.

To find the day when the principal plus aggregated interest reaches $150, use this:

`C1`:
`=+filter(A2:A, B2:B >= 150)`

See [Compound interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest).

Answer (score 1):

You can "trick" one of the financial functions into returning the answer, e.g.,

`=ROUND(NPER(-(4%)/365,0,-150,100))`

This will return the number of days until the target amount is reached. (You can add `/365` to the end to get an answer in years, or `/12` to get an answer in months.)

`NPER` is short for "**N**umber of **PER**iods."

All of the parameters should be clear against your example figures from the post, except for perhaps the 0, which means "no contributions are being made other than pure interest."